# Packery and imagesLoaded plugin not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, packery, imagesloaded

I'm using Packery on a website and have downloaded imagesLoaded, but still my images overlap on page load. The website can be seen [here](http://www.educ.dab.uts.edu.au/Web-Media/10722724/cdg.html) and my code is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $container = $container.packery({
   itemSelector: "packery-item"
});
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
   container.packery();
});
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** The html code looks like this:

```
<div class="packery js-packery">

<div class="packery-item item"><img src="imgs/cdg5.jpg"></img></div>
<div class="packery-item text"><img src="imgs/text1.png"></img></div>
<div class="packery-item item w2"><img src="imgs/cdg3.jpg"></img></div>
<div class="packery-item gif"><img src="imgs/gif1.gif"></img></div>

</div>
```

etc.

Comment: Could you include your html code? I have had the same problem because of images in my tiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that packery is executed before the images in your items are loaded. Because of that Packery can not know how high the element will have to be.

A solution for this is to check with jquery if all images are loaded and then execute Packery. I have found several ways to do this, the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached) seems like a good one.

Another way to fix this is to give the images a fixed height in css or with an height attribute. However, you can only do this when the images have the same height or when you know the height in advance.

**Update:**
This is an example code for the first solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var cnt = $("img").length;
    $("img").one("load", function() {
        cnt--;

        // If all images are loaded, init Packery
        if (cnt === 0)
        {
            $(".js-packery").packery({
               itemSelector: "packery-item"
            });
        }

    }).each(function() {
      if(this.complete) $(this).load();
    });

});
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, but exactly where would the callback go within the current jQuery code?

Comment: In your document ready you should put a loop that checks all the images. If all those images are loaded, initialize Packery. I have added an example code.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but it doesn't seem to work for my browsers?

Comment: Line 12: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'packery' of undefined"

Comment: You need to set the variable `$container` to your container element before using the variable. I have edited my code.

Comment: You're incredible! Thank you so much :^]